# RTF To XML in WPF (C#)

Tags: wpf, xml, richtextbox, rtf

Please, tell me, how can I convert RTF to XML in WPF (C#). I am interesting in native methods. Text in RichTextBox can be formatted differently, also in the RichTextBox can be inserted pictures, etc...

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way. You will need to parse the RTF file and then convert it to XML. There is tutorial at codeproject which might be of your interest :- [Formatting Text in a RichTextBox by Parsing the Rich Text Format](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RTFSyntaxColour.aspx)